# Plotting mean and st-dev from a dataset with multiple y values for an x value

Tags: r

My data is organized as such:

```
Distance r^2
0        1
0        0.9
0        0
0        0.8
0        1 
1        0.5 
1        0.45
1        0.56
1        1
2        0  
2        0.9
3        0
3        0.1
3        0.2
3        0.3
...
300      1 
300      0.8
```

I want to plot r^2 decay with distance, meaning I want to plot a mean value + st-dev for every unique distance value. So I should have 1 point at x=0, 1 point at x=1... but I have multiple x=0 values.

What is the best way to achieve this, given how the data is organized? I would like to do it in R if possible.

Thank you,
Adrian

Edit:
I have tried:

```
> dd <-structure(list(Distance = dist18, r.2 = a18[,13]), Names = c("Distance",   "r^2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
> ggplot(dd, aes(x=Distance, y=r.2)) + stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl")
Error in data.frame(x = c(42L, 209L, 105L, 168L, 63L, 212L, 148L, 175L,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 126877, 15
> head(dist18)
[1]  42 209 105 168  63 212
> head(dd)
Distance  r.2
1       42 0.89
2      209 0.92
3      105 0.91
4      168 0.81
5       63 0.88
6      212 0.88
```

Is this because my data is not sorted?

Answer (score 1):

You can also plot your SD as an area around the mean similar to CI plotting (assuming `temp` is your data set)

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
temp <- setDT(temp)[, list(Mean = mean(r.2), SD = sd(r.2)), by = Distance]
ggplot(temp) + geom_point(aes(Distance, Mean)) + geom_ribbon(aes(x = Distance, y = Mean, ymin = (Mean - SD), ymax = (Mean + SD)), fill = "skyblue", alpha = 0.4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` it will be something like this:

```
df = data.frame(distance = rep(1:300, each = 10), r2 = runif(3000))

library(dplyr)
df_group = group_by(df, distance)
summarise(df_group, mn = mean(r2), s = sd(r2))Source: local data frame [300 x 3]
   distance        mn         s
1       300 0.4977758 0.3565554
2       299 0.4295891 0.3281598
3       297 0.5346428 0.3424429
4       296 0.4623368 0.3163320
5       291 0.3224376 0.2103655
6       290 0.3916658 0.2115264
7       288 0.6147680 0.2953960
8       287 0.3405524 0.2032616
9       286 0.5690844 0.2458538
10      283 0.2901744 0.2835524
..      ...       ...       ...
```

Where `df` is the data.frame with your data, and `distance` and `r2` the two column names.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot mean and +/- 1 sd for each point, the `ggplot function` makes this easy. With the test data

```
dd<-structure(list(Distance = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), r.2 = c(1, 0.9, 0, 0.8, 1, 0.5, 0.45, 
0.56, 1, 0, 0.9, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3)), .Names = c("Distance", "r.2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

you can just run

```
library(Hmisc)

ggplot(dd, aes(x=Distance, y=r.2)) +
   stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl", mult=1)
```

which produces

[image]

I tried with your real data and got

```
real <- read.table("http://pelinfamily.ca/bio/GDR-18_conc.ld", header=F)
dd <- data.frame(Distance=real[,2]-real[,1], r.2=real[,13])

ggplot(dd, aes(x=Distance, y=r.2)) +
   stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl", mult=1, geom="ribbon", alpha=.4) + 
   stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl", mult=1, geom="line")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, I got this:> ggplot(dd, aes(x=Distance, y=r.2)) + stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl")
Error in data.frame(x = c(42L, 209L, 105L, 168L, 63L, 212L, 148L, 175L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 126877, 15
> head(dist18)
[1]  42 209 105 168  63 212

Comment: That's what you get running the exact code above? What versions of the packages do you have? I used Hmisc_3.14-4  and ggplot2_1.0.0.

Comment: both version are identical to mine. Must be something about the data that I am not showing right. Do you mind trying it on my real data? http://pelinfamily.ca/bio/GDR-18_conc.ld ; distance is "column2-column1"(minus) and r^2 is column13.

Comment: @AdrianP. I updated my solution using the real data. I'm not sure col 13 is `r^2` because if it is that's an odd patten for low values at a small distance.

Comment: I must have done something wrong. Thanks you, this works great!

Comment: I have trouble interpreting this too... But it does look similar to what they see here in Figure 4 (http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0048588#s3) But you are right that at a very small distance the pattern is odd...

Comment: Now I am trying to plot multiple samples in the same grid, but they do not all end at the same xlimit. How can I force them all to end at 300? I am using pushViewport

Comment: Did you try setting `xlim()`? I don't quite understand what you are doing but it sounds different from this question. Maybe you should start another with this new issue.

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

```
# Create a data frame like yours

df=data.frame(sample(50,size=300,replace=TRUE),runif(300))
colnames(df)=c('Distance','r^2')

#initialize empty data frame with columns x, mean and stdev

results=data.frame(x=numeric(0),mean=numeric(0),stdev=numeric(0))
count=1 
for (i in 0:max(df$Distance)){
    results[count,'x']=i
    temp_mean=mean(df[which(df$Distance==i),'r^2'])
    results[count,'mean']=temp_mean
    temp_sd=sd(df[which(df$Distance==i),'r^2'])
    results[count,'stdev']=temp_sd
    count=count+1
}
# Plot your results
plot(results$x,results$mean,xlab='distance',ylab='r^2')

epsilon=0.02 #to add the little horizontal bar to the error bars
for (i in 1:nrow(results)){
     up = results$mean[i] + results$stdev[i]
    low = results$mean[i] - results$stdev[i]
    segments(results$x[i],low , results$x[i], up)
    segments(results$x[i]-epsilon, up , results$x[i]+epsilon, up)
    segments(results$x[i]-epsilon, low , results$x[i]+epsilon, low)
}
```

Here's the result https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx58C.jpg